# how to get the count of records in a season

Tags: mysql, sql, database

my table's fields are `id`,`name`,`date_confirm(yyyy-mm-dd h:i:s)`.
i want get number of records confirmed in summer or winter or ... .
result for example:

`18|summer 2015`

`17|Autumn 2015`

`0|winter 2015`

`1|spring 2016`

how to group by column for this?

Comment: is this mysql or sql-server? you've tagged both

Comment: this is mysql..

Comment: Provide some sample data and what the beginning and end dates are for each season

Comment: give groupby to season name and year

Answer (score 0):

```
select count(id)
from yourTable
where
    date(date_confirm) between date(seasonBegin) and date(seasonEnd)
;
```

You can throw this in the body of a procedure and then pass the beginning and end of the season you are looking for based on how your app defines seasons. I chose to count on the id field as it is the only one i can assume is not null.

Comment: this is not true.i want get result in one query.

Comment: Maybe you should edit your question to use the word and instead of or

Answer (score 0):

```
select count(1) ,name
from yourtable
group by name
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
SUM(CASE WHEN date_confirm BETWEEN(begindate, enddate)THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Confirmed_Summer2015
,SUM(CASE WHEN date_confirm BETWEEN(begindate, enddate)THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Confirmed_Autumn2015
--Keep adding more seasons if needed
FROM TableName
```

And just keep following that pattern using the beginning and ending dates of whatever season you're interested in.